# Merging/joining on candidates index in row

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas dataframe, there's a column called `candidates`. This column gives a list with several indices.

| Index | Column 1 | Candidates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 34 | [2,3,22] |
| 1 | 42 | [0,4,30,9] |
| 2 | 231 | ... |
| 3 | 123 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

I'm looking for joining/merging the dataframe with itself according to those candidates, just like in the example below...

| Index | Column 1 | Index | Column 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 34 | 2 | 231 |
| 0 | 34 | 3 | 123 |
| 0 | 34 | 22 | 45 |
| 1 | 42 | 0 | 34 |
| 1 | 42 | 4 | 900 |
| 1 | 42 | 30 | 87 |

How does one do this in pandas?

Note: Column 1_y values come from Column 1, in the original dataframe.

Comment: From where are the values `Column 1_y` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely It's from the original dataframe. Notice that for index 0, we have 34. If you check the row with index 0, column 1 value is 34.

Comment: No, we want to know where `231` to set the value of `Column_1_y` came from

Comment: Andrej meant the `231`/`123`/… values

Comment: @mozway 231 is column 1 value for index 2, 123 is column 1 value for index 3... All this is from the original dataframe.

Comment: It's not clear what you are matching on. What do 231 and 34 have in common? Maybe you could fill out the Candidates column a little more.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. it would be ideal to provide the DataFrame constructor of a minimal and complete example, that would avoid many ambiguities (are those real lists? what should happen if you don't have a match? etc.) See my answer for the general logic and an example of reproducible input ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (after a [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)):

```
out = (df
   .explode('Candidates')
   .merge(df[['Index', 'Column 1']]
          .rename(columns={'Index': 'Candidates'}),
          on='Candidates', how='left'
         )
)
```

Output:

```
   Index  Column 1_x Candidates  Column 1_y
0      0          34          2       231.0
1      0          34          3       123.0
2      0          34         22         NaN
3      1          42          0        34.0
4      1          42          4         NaN
5      1          42         30         NaN
6      1          42          9         NaN
7      2         231        NaN         NaN
8      3         123        NaN         NaN
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Column 1': [34, 42, 231, 123],
                   'Candidates': [[2, 3, 22], [0, 4, 30, 9], [], []]})
```

##### if "Index" is the index:

```
out = (df
   .explode('Candidates')
   .merge(df[['Column 1']],
          left_on='Candidates', right_index=True, how='left'
         )
)
```

Output:

```
   Column 1_x Candidates  Column 1_y
0          34          2       231.0
0          34          3       123.0
0          34         22         NaN
1          42          0        34.0
1          42          4         NaN
1          42         30         NaN
1          42          9         NaN
2         231        NaN         NaN
3         123        NaN         NaN
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': [34, 42, 231, 123],
                   'Candidates': [[2, 3, 22], [0, 4, 30, 9], [], []]},
                 index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: mozway, hum... I understand your comment now...
The index in my example is the index of the dataframe. In you r example it's a column... How would we adapt to this case?

Comment: Many thanks! I think that's it. I was missing the how kwarg! I'll double check and then I'll